# Find the argument of $\dfrac{(3-2i)(1-i)}{(2+i)^2}$

Tags: complex-numbers

As the header suggests, I am supposed to find the argument for the complex number  $\dfrac{(3-2i)(1-i)}{(2+i)^2}$

This is how I've tried:

Approach 1: Calculate the arguments by factoring out the absolute value and use product and division rules:
$\arg((3-2i) = \arg\left( \sqrt{13}\left(\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{13}} - \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{13}}\right) \right) \iff \cos(x) = \dfrac{3}{\sqrt{13}} \land \sin(x) = \dfrac{-2}{\sqrt{13}}$
But I do not know the inverses for these values, so the method already fails.

Approach 2:
I also get some strange values which I do not know the inverse values of when I try to rewrite it as
$\dfrac{(3-2i)(1-i)}{(2+i)^2} = \dfrac{(3-2i)(2-i)}{(2+i)(2-i)} \cdot \dfrac{(1-i)(2-i)}{(2+i)(2-i)}$

So this method also fails.

Approach 3:
The only method I could think of now is to write each of the factors arguments and the denominators argument in terms of $\arctan$ But I do not get anywhere with that method either. Is there an easy method to solve the problem?

Comment: For your 2nd approach, the things that you multiply on is not 1......

Comment: @user3313320 oops, my mistake, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT it would be simpler to simplify the fraction, by multiplying the brackets out, first **before** attempting to multiply by the conjugate

Comment: Oh thank you, I completely forgot I could use $\arctan$ in method 2 too.

Answer (score 2):

You may also use
$$ \arg(a+bi)=\arctan\left(\frac{b}{a}\right) $$
and the arctangent addition formula
$$ \arctan(u)+\arctan(v)  = \arctan\left(\frac{u+v}{1-uv}\right) $$
to get a result that is the right one up to a multiple of $\pi$. Also notice that:
$$ \arg\frac{(3-2i)(1-i)}{(2+i)^2}=\arg\frac{1-5i}{3+4i}=\arg\left((1-5i)(3-4i)\right)=\arg\left(-17-19i\right).$$

Comment: The last part was very helpful, thanks!

Comment: @PandaDeTapas: you're welcome.